# A monad with a "real" return function

Tags: haskell, monads

A common beginner's mistake is to see `return` and think that it's a language keyword that exits the current function with a return value. Of course, we know that isn't what it does at all. But I wonder... could we actually *make* such a function? Purely for argument's sake, at this point.

It seems we're looking for some monad `Foo` which possesses a function

```
exit :: x -> Foo x
```

which will abort the rest of the computation and immediately return `x`.

Is such a thing constructable? If it could be constructed, would it be *useful*? Is this even a sane thing to attempt to do?

Comment: You can certainly build something like it in the continuation monad, except the return type wouldn't be what you wrote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible in the `Cont` monad. The `Cont` is defined as follows:

```
newtype Cont r a = Cont {runCont :: (a -> r) -> r}

instance Monad (Cont r) where
    return a = Cont ($ a)
    m >>= k = Cont $ \c -> runCont m $ \a -> runCont (k a) c
```

Now we can create `exit` as follows:

```
exit = Cont . const
```

In fact you can do it in *almost* any monad (for example you could do it in the `Either` monad but not in the `State` monad). However the `Cont` monad is the mother of all monads: http://blog.sigfpe.com/2008/12/mother-of-all-monads.html

Comment: `Cont` is way overkill for this. Just use `Either` or something simpler.

Comment: Also, it's not true that you can do it in any monad. (It's also not true that `Cont` is "the mother of all monads" -- that's actually `Codensity` -- but it's close enough. Either way, that should probably be a hint that you *shouldn't* use it when something much simpler does exactly what you want.)

Answer (score 5):

Of course it's doable.  It's even already in the standard libraries. You just need a slightly saner type signature.

```
import Control.Monad

exit :: a -> Either a b
exit = Left

main = print $ do
    x <- Right 5
    exit "foo"
    error "this is a good place to crash"
```

The important thing to note is that the type given when bailing out isn't free - it has to match the type of the Either.

Comment: Technically this doesn't match the type required in the question :-)

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Yes. That's why I said you need a better type.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to satisfy the monad laws, you certainly can't call it `return` since we need that `return a >>= f = f a`.

Also, I don't think it can exist at all with the precise specification given. Suppose `x :: a` and `f :: a -> Foo b`, then just following the types, `exit a >>= f :: Foo b` yet we want it to produce `x :: a`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you can just about implement this:

```
data Foo e x =
  Next x |
  Done e

instance Monad (Foo e) where
  return = Next

  (Next x) >>= f = f x
  (Done e) >>= f = Done e

exit :: e -> Foo e x
exit = Done

run :: Foo x x -> x
run (Next x) = x
run (Done x) = x
```

Notice how the monad has an extra type parameter; I don't think it's possible to avoid this. Basically `Foo e x` produces an `x` and will "ultimately" produce an `e`. Note that the `run` function requires both types to match; you could equally demand that `run` only works if `exit` gets called *somewhere*, or one of a few other possibilities...

So, yes you can construct this, and no, it's not especially useful AFAIK.

Comment: Isn't that just the `Either` monad?

Comment: This is exactly the the `Either` monad, and it's used heavily through the `Error` alias.

Comment: @bennofs: Possibly, yes.

Comment: In the `Either` monad, early exit is synonymous with failure. This doesn't necessarily have to be the case (e.g., you could _require_ that `exit` gets called eventually).

Comment: You could have `data Exit e r = Error e | Done r | Next r`, then have your `Monad (Error e)` instance as `Error e >>= f = Error e`, `Done r >>= f = Done r`, and `Next r >>= f = f r` with `return = Next`.  That would give you the ability to exit a computation early and still have error handling

Comment: @bheklir compare to `type Partiality = Free Maybe`